# New feature class with matching records ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins, feature-class

I have two feature classes in a FGDB each with a set of time stamped points. Let's call them `fc1` and `fc2`. Between these two feature classes one or the other does not consistently have a greater number of points, sometimes `fc1` will have more and other times `fc2` will.

I want to create two new feature classes (`fc1_join` and `fc2_join`) that only contain matching records based on the timestamp. In the end `fc1_join` and `fc2_join` should have an equal number of features, correct?

And what steps would be taken to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two output feature classes would only have equal number of records ***if the relationship based on the time stamp was always one-to-one***.

If you ever had, for example, three records in `fc1` with a the same time stamp, which also matched a single record in `fc2`, then `fc1_join` would contain two more records for that match than `fc2_join` would.

***Assuming the time stamps were always unique (which would mean only one-to-one joins would be possible) here is how to do do these joins in ArcMap.***

- Right-click on `fc1` in the table of contents window and choose *Joins and Relates* > *Join...*, which opens the *Join Data* dialog box:
- Keep *Join attributes from a table* in the first drop-down
- 1. Choose the time stamp field in `fc1`
- 2. Choose `fc2`
- 3. Choose the time stamp field from `fc2`
- Keep only matching records
- OK
- Now export the data by right-clicking `fc1` in the table of contents and choosing *Data* > *Export Data...* from the context menu. This will export a new feature class (you can name it `fc1_join`) containing only those features from `fc1` that had a time stamp match in `fc2`, along with the joined attributes from `fc2`.
- After you've exported `fc1_join`, right-click `fc1` in the table of contents and choose *Joins and Relates* > *Remove Join(s)...*.

To create `fc2_join`, repeat the steps above but invert `fc2` for `fc1`.

Comment: The time stamps are always unique in each feature class.